# Why am I getting an error in my ElasticSearch query after upgrading to 1.3.2?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Before, I had this:

```
{
  query: {
    function_score: {
      filter: {
        and: [
          {
            term: {
              'currency': 'usd',
              '_cache': false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      script_score: {
        "script": "_score * doc['random_score'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Very basic, I just filter by currency and sort by a score.

But every since I upgraded, I can't get any simple custom score query to work.

I've tried to simplify it with this example:

```
{
  query: {
    function_score: {
      script_score: {
        "script": "_score * doc['random_score'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm getting errors such as:

```
{
  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[PxzZtO8FQviuhxS-3EJFwA][listings][3]:
            SearchParseException[[listings][3]: from[-1],size[-1]:
              Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
                {
                  "query": {
                    "function_score": {
                      "script_score": {
                        "script": "_score * doc['random_score'].value"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]]];
            nested: QueryParsingException[[listings] script_score the script could not be loaded];
            nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [mvel] disabled]; }{[PxzZtO8FQviuhxS-3EJFwA][listings][4]:
            SearchParseException[[listings][4]: from[-1],size[-1]:
              Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
                {
                  "query": {
                    "function_score": {
                      "script_score": {
                        "script": "_score * doc['random_score'].value"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]]];
            nested: QueryParsingException[[listings] script_score the script could not be loaded];
            nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [mvel] disabled]; }{[PxzZtO8FQviuhxS-3EJFwA][listings][0]:
            SearchParseException[[listings][0]: from[-1],size[-1]:
              Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
                {
                  "query": {
                    "function_score": {
                      "script_score": {
                        "script": "_score * doc['random_score'].value"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]]];
            nested: QueryParsingException[[listings] script_score the script could not be loaded];
            nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [mvel] disabled]; }{[PxzZtO8FQviuhxS-3EJFwA][listings][1]:
            SearchParseException[[listings][1]: from[-1],size[-1]:
              Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
                {
                  "query": {
                    "function_score": {
                      "script_score": {
                        "script": "_score * doc['random_score'].value"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]]];
            nested: QueryParsingException[[listings] script_score the script could not be loaded];
            nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [mvel] disabled]; }{[PxzZtO8FQviuhxS-3EJFwA][listings][2]:
            SearchParseException[[listings][2]: from[-1],size[-1]:
              Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
                {
                  "query": {
                    "function_score": {
                      "script_score": {
                        "script": "_score * doc['random_score'].value"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]]];
            nested: QueryParsingException[[listings] script_score the script could not be loaded];
            nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [mvel] disabled]; }]",
  "status": 400
}
```

Something very simple such as this, works:

```
{
  query: {
    match_all: {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In previous version mvel was  scripting in elasticsearch, now depreciated.

Here is a issue for that. https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/7029

Actual problem is dynamic scripting for mvel is not supported in 1.3.x, but it is the default language in 1.3.x also, will be changed in 1.4.x, so you have to include lang parameter, and give value as, (lang=groovy)

```
{
    query:{
        function_score:{
            script_score : {
                "script" : "_score * doc['random_score'].value",
                "lang":"groovy"
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!! Thanks

Comment: As it is only deprected it should work using the script from the config/scripts folder (?) How can I make this happen for a separate ES installation? Installing a plugin? For an maven application that directly integrates ES I can just add `<groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
   <artifactId>elasticsearch-lang-mvel</artifactId>`

Comment: It will not work for mvel, you have to install it (yes as a plugin) , 
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-mvel/
After you install, you can use, lang : "mvel"